# go mod download fails with "Repository not found" error

Tags: git, go, github

The error began after I attempted to update all my local repositories via this command:

`find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin main \;`

After that, go mod download began failing:

`go: github.com/{user-group}/{repo}@v0.0.0-20230802183648-af0063b569b4: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/{my username}/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ea636087773376e04ca12de1627070553b418775753e435c06b5cc7e636f1353: exit status 128:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`
```

My go.mod file:

`module github.com/{user-group}/{repo}

go 1.19

require github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6`

My go.sum file:

`github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6 h1:BKbKCqvP6I+rmFHt06ZmyQtvB8xAkWdhFyr0ZUNZcxQ= github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6/go.mod h1:v8dTdLbMG2kIc/vJvl+f65V22dbkXbowE6jgT/gNBxE= golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543 h1:E7g+9GITq07hpfrRu66IVDexMakfv52eLZ2CXBWiKr4= golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543/go.mod h1:I/5z698sn9Ka8TeJc9MKroUUfqBBauWjQqLJ2OPfmY0=`

My OS is mac.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out what the problem was. Going to the directory `/Users/{my username}/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ea636087773376e04ca12de1627070553b418775753e435c06b5cc7e636f1353` and running `git config --list` on it and on my repository I found that the values of `remote.origin.url` were different. Changing the value in `ea636087773376e04ca12de1627070553b418775753e435c06b5cc7e636f1353` to be the same as the value in my repository via `git remote set-url origin` fixed the issue.

Comment: You should not be modifying anything in `GOPATH/pkg` in the first place, that should only be managed by the `go` tool. You can always just remove the cache and let the tool rebuild it correcly.